# Best way to develop PHP with a team?

Tags: php, version-control

I am working on PHP project with a group of 4. I am wondering what is the best way to develop the project.

We have a version control system.

I am confused about how each developer writes and tests code. Should each developer have his/her own test environment? Is it best to have that test environment local? Etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each developer should have their own local environment on their machine to do development on. Once a developer has implemented a particurlar feature, he should commit it to the version control system.

You should use a continuous integration tool to automatically build the latest code from the version control system into a staging environment. I use beanstalk for version control and automated deployments.

Once you are happy with the code in the staging environment, you can manually build this to the production environment.

This is a simple but flexible system that is suitable for a 4 person team

Answer (score 1):

Two pieces of advice:

First, each person should understand group coding standards. Often, people have discrepancies in capitalization, underscore use, and variable naming; when working on a project with multiple people, this often becomes confusing. Make sure that is standardized.

Each developer should test in their local environment. If the tests work, they commit with a changelog detailing the changes. Make sure if you're working in a group of more than two that each person gives detailed changelogs. Otherwise, it becomes impossible to figure out what revision changed what.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of things to keep in mind when working in a team (in no particular order):

1. Make sure each developer has an identical environment for local development.
2. A version control system like git is a must. Every member should push commits regularly. you don't want someone pushing 10 commits in a go, only to cause a number of merge conflicts on others' local setups.

   Also, make sure you use version control effectively. Maintain `master` (or any other) as your production branch, which is always deployable. Work in other branches for other features.
3. Before starting work, discuss the application architecture thoroughly. You might even want to look into [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) so that different parts of code are well-separate and division of work is easier.
4. Write rigorous unit tests for every feature you develop. [Test-driven development](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html) is often the most efficient approach to developing in a team.
5. Also, like *@Telthien* pointed out, maintain a common styleguide ([Github](https://github.com/styleguide)'s and [Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/)'s for reference). This involves stuff like using spaces/tabs for indentation, starting function names with underscore, title-casing class names, and so on.

Comment: Also consider a CI setup that is triggered by every push to the version control system to execute lint checks, run unit tests, do phpdepend and phpmd, verify that code matches defined standards using codesniffer, generate API docs (to confirm that all docblocks are defined and correct), etc

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends entirely on your needs.

What I normally do in small teams is have a local test environment for each developer.  Better yet if you have a VM image of a good test server that can be regularly updated and distributed for each developer to test on, so that your testing closely matches your production environment.

Comment: Tools like puppet or chef are excellent for provisioning a consistent development VM

Comment: @MarkBaker, Good to know!  I haven't used them before... I will look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: Puppet and chef can be used with Vagrant to make it even easier for developers to have a development environment that is consistent between developers and with production.

You don't have to distribute a new VM image if your want to upgrade the version of PHP or add dependencies on new extensions, for example.  You just commit the puppet/chef configuration changes to your version control system.